# Error: variables were specified with different types from the fit

Tags: r

In `car`package, I am trying to predict the response variable called `prestige` in a dataset also named `Prestige` based on `income`, `education`, and factor `type` by `lm` function. But before I fit data, I want to scale `education` and `income`. The code below if you copy and run it in R stuido, the console would say `Error: variables ‘income’, ‘I(income^2)’, ‘education’, ‘I(education^2)’ were specified with different types from the fit`

```
library(car)
summary(Prestige)
Prestige$education <- scale(Prestige$education)

Prestige$income <- scale(Prestige$income)

fit <- lm(prestige ~ income + I(income^2) + education + I(education^2)
          + income:education + type + type:income + type:I(income^2) 
          + type:education + type:I(education^2)+ type:income:education, Prestige)
summary(fit)
pred <- expand.grid(income = c(1000, 20000), education = c(10,20),type = levels(Prestige $ type))
pred $ prestige.pred <- predict(fit, newdata = pred)
pred
```

Without scaling the predictors, it can successfully work. So the error is definitely due to the scaling before prediction and I am wondering how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that `scale()` actually change the class of your columns. See

```
class(car::Prestige$education)
# [1] "numeric"
class(scale(car::Prestige$education))
# [1] "matrix"
```

You would be safe simplying them to numeric vectors. You can use the dimension-stripping properties of `c()` for this

```
Prestige$education <- c(scale(Prestige$education))
Prestige$income <- c(scale(Prestige$income))
```

Then I was able to run your model with

```
fit <- lm(prestige ~ income + I(income^2) + education + I(education^2)
          + income:education + type + type:income + type:I(income^2) 
          + type:education + type:I(education^2)+ type:income:education,
          Prestige, na.action="na.omit")
```

and the prediction returned

```
   income education type prestige.pred
1    1000        10   bc    -1352364.5
2   20000        10   bc  -533597423.4
3    1000        20   bc    -1382361.7
4   20000        20   bc  -534229639.3
5    1000        10 prof      398464.2
6   20000        10 prof   155567014.1
7    1000        20 prof      409271.3
8   20000        20 prof   155765754.7
9    1000        10   wc    -7661464.3
10  20000        10   wc -3074382169.9
11   1000        20   wc    -7634693.8
12  20000        20   wc -3073902696.6
```

Also note you cam simplify your formula somewhat with

```
fit<-lm(prestige ~ (income + I(income^2) + education + I(education^2))*type +
          income:education + type:income:education, Prestige, na.action="na.omit")
```

This uses `*` to create many of the interaction terms.

Answer (score 6):

`scale()` adds attributes that seem to create problems with `lm()`. Using

```
Prestige$education <- as.numeric(scale(Prestige$education))     
Prestige$education <- as.numeric(scale(Prestige$income))
```

make everything works.