# R shiny shows error when I use reactive object in predict function

Tags: r, shiny

I am not able to find where it is wrong. The predict function I think is not working properly and also it shows the new_depression with appropriate values and then in answers object it shows features of the new_depression  were specified with different types from the fit. How is it not working, maybe predict function is not working properly. Please help!!!

library(shiny)

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel( 
      radioButtons(inputId="first", label="a",  choices = list("None" = 0,"Little" = 1,"Some" = 2,"Much" = 3,"Most" = 4),selected = 1),
                    radioButtons(inputId="second", label="a", c("None" = 0,"Little" = 1,"Some" = 2,"Much" = 3,"Most" = 4)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="third", label="a", c("None" = 0,"Little" = 1,"Some" = 2,"Much" = 3,"Most" = 4)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="fourth", label="a", c("None" = 0,"Little" = 1,"Some" = 2,"Much" = 3,"Most" = 4)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="fifth", label="a", c("None" = 0,"Little" = 1,"Some" = 2,"Much" = 3,"Most" = 4)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="sixth", label="a", c("None" = 0,"Little" = 1,"Some" = 2,"Much" = 3,"Most" = 4)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="seventh", label="a", c("None" = 0,"Little" = 1,"Some" = 2,"Much" = 3,"Most" = 4)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="eighth", label="a", c("None" = 0,"Little" = 1,"Some" = 2,"Much" = 3,"Most" = 4)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="ninth", label="a", c("None" = 0,"Little" = 1,"Some" = 2,"Much" = 3,"Most" = 4)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="tenth", label="a", c("None" = 0,"Little" = 1,"Some" = 2,"Much" = 3,"Most" = 4)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="eleventh", label="a", c("Yes" = 1,"No" = 0)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="twelfth", label="a", c("Yes" = 1,"No" = 0)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="thirteenth", label="a", c("Yes" = 1,"No" = 0)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="fourteenth", label="a", c("Yes" = 1,"No" = 0)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="fifteenth", label="a", c("Yes" = 1,"No" = 0)),
                    radioButtons(inputId="sixteenth", label="a", c("Yes" = 1,"No" = 0)),
                    submitButton("Submit")),
      mainPanel(
                    tableOutput(outputId= "ans"),
                    uiOutput(outputId= "abc")

      ))
    )

    server <- function(input, output){ 

      new_depression <- reactive({ data.frame("ASadness"=input$first,
                                   "Loconcen"=input$second,
                                   "Asleep"=input$third,
                                   "Aappet"=input$fourth,
                                   "Loenergy"=input$fifth,
                                   "Foguilt"=input$sixth,
                                   "Asbehav"=input$seventh,
                                   "Sthough"=input$eighth,
                                   "Ppains"=input$ninth,
                                   "Eactivity"=input$tenth,
                                   "Wloss"=input$eleventh,
                                   "Ssupport"=input$twelfth,
                                   "Etdsthin"=input$thirteenth,
                                   "Dmaking"=input$fourteenth,
                                   "Fhopilln"=input$fifteenth,
                                   "Addiction"=input$sixteenth)
      })


        library(caret)
        depression_model <- read.csv("C:/Users/Project/web/depression_with_nd_p.csv" , header=TRUE , stringsAsFactors = F) 



        str(depression_model)
        head(depression_model )

        set.seed(3233)
        intrain <- createDataPartition(y = depression_model$Depression, p= 0.7, list = FALSE)
        training <- depression_model[intrain,]
        testing <- depression_model[-intrain,]

        dim(training)
        dim(testing)

        anyNA(depression_model)
        summary(depression_model)

        training[["Depression"]] = factor(training[["Depression"]])

        trctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3)
        set.seed(3233)

        svm_Linear <- train(Depression ~., data = training, method = "svmLinear",
                            trControl=trctrl,
                            preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                            tuneLength = 10)

        svm_Linear
        summary(svm_Linear)

        test_pred <- predict(svm_Linear, newdata = testing)
        test_pred

        tab <- table(Predicted = test_pred, Actual = testing$Depression )
        tab

        1 - sum(diag(tab))/sum(tab)

        #I think the problem is here in new_depression
        answers <- reactive({
          predict(svm_Linear, newdata=new_depression())
        })

      #This works ok and it also shows the features of my dataset with the selected 
      #attributes I choose using radio buttons
      output$ans <- renderTable(new_depression())
      #Here it shows error that features of my dataset  were specified with 
      #different types from the fit
      output$abc <- renderUI({answers()})
    }


    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It's going to be much easier to help you and debug your program if you can make it minimally reproducible. For example, as a start, include the dataset so that we can run the code ourselves

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is shiny related. I got this error when trying to run your code:

```
Warning: Error in : variables ‘ASadness’, ‘Loconcen’, ‘Asleep’, ‘Aappet’, ‘Loenergy’, ‘Foguilt’, ‘Asbehav’, ‘Sthough’, ‘Ppains’, ‘Eactivity’, ‘Wloss’, ‘Ssupport’, ‘Etdsthin’, ‘Dmaking’, ‘Fhopilln’, ‘Addiction’ were specified with different types from the fit
```

[No stack trace available]

That doesn't look like a shiny error. I googled for that error and here's the first search result: [Error: variables were specified with different types from the fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218003/error-variables-were-specified-with-different-types-from-the-fit)

In that answer it seems like they claim that using "scale" could be the culprit.